# how to convert class diagram (association relation) to code

Tags: php, oop

i planned to work with class diagram in my e-commerce website project . I have good idea in OOP but there are some subjects i'm not familiar with it , such as code the association relation in the class diagram , i'm know the basic and the easy example of that subject. but i want to use it in A practical example.

[image: my class diagram]

This is my class diagram example ,, and i want to understand what i must do with ORDER  class and CUSTOMER  class , how can i relate ORDER class with Customer class. i'm really confused and want to explanation this subject.

Comment: What does this have to do with php? It's very unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

a customer has orders, so you add an `orders` property to your `Customer`:

```
class Customer {

    protected $orders;

    public function addOrder(Order $order)
    {
        $this->orders[] = $order;
    }
}
```

A `Customer` is required for an `Order`, so add it as a constructor argument, which manages the other side of the relation:

```
class Order {

    protected $customer;

    public function __construct(Customer $customer)
    {
        $this->customer = $customer;
        $customer->addOrder($this);
    }
}
```

To determine these things, just say the relations out loud:

- "a Customer has many Orders" boom, array of Order in Customer.
- "an Order Belongs to a Customer" boom, Customer property in Order
- ...